# Modification of build events and project dependencies programmatically

Tags: c#

In my project, I use a template wizard to include projects from project templates. I also need to programmatically set the project dependencies and build actions programmatically

Comment: That's quiet a task...what's your question?

Comment: How can I programmatically modify build events of a template that I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I wrote a "dependency embedder" which automatically embedded all dependencies a specified assembly. I just had to read the affected files (csproj, resx,...) and insert everything I need programmatically.
Maybe there is a better, built in way to manage this, but this is how I did it and it worked.

You also have to get the content of the csproj file and search for the line you need.
If you want to modify the PostBuildEvents you have to search for lines like this

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>Your PostBuildEvents</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

or add it if you haven't already set any PostBuildEvents.

I hope this could help you (or anyone else who has the same problem).